# Why does running a thread loop within an AWT component prevent the WindowHandler from executing?

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, awt

I modified the sample code for `Activator` posted on the Oracle/Sun AWT tutorial page [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/awt/contents.html#AWTAWTAdapters)

The modification is as follows

```
f.add(new MyCanvas(f.getGraphicsConfiguration()), 
             BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The paint method in MyCanvas is overridden as follows

```
MyCustomRunnable mcr = new MyCustomRunnable();
Thread th = new Thread(mcr);

th.start();

while(Thread.currentThread().isAlive()){
    mcr.getData();
    //do UI stuff 
    Thread.yield();
}
```

Similarly `MyCustomRunnable` has a corresponding loop in `run()`

```
public void run(){
    while(Thread.currentThread().isAlive){
        //do Stuff
        Thread.yield();
    }
}
```

The `Runnable`, and Canvas paint (both) run a loop. With this bit of code running, System Menu close on the UI window are not invoked. Why?

Comment: Why code using AWT components in this millennium?  Most people who did use it have forgotten how, and the answers are less valuable because of that.

Comment: No offence, but ... because it's there (+: 
It's what was going around when I started to learn java in the 00s so when I had to do some stuff that required UI, I chose to go with the relatively familiar stuff to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `paint()` is called on the event thread, which is also the thread that handles all UI events, and you are taking over that thread and putting it into an infinite loop.

When you are doing this in the paint method...

```
while(Thread.currentThread().isAlive()){
   ...
}
```

... the "current thread" you are working on is the same thread you entered that method on, which is the "event dispatch thread". I would guess that what you really wanted was to run a background thread that periodically repaints the view. You could do this in the constructor of your AWT component:

```
new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      while(runBackgroundThread) {
         mcr.getData();
         repaint();
      }
   }
}.start();
```

Note that I also created a boolean variable `runBackgroundThread` which would be a volatile field in the component class. Setting it false would stop the loading thread. In contrast, `Thread.currentThread().isAlive()` will **always** be true - the currently running thread must by definition be alive.

Answer (score 3):

0Almost certainly because your thread is keeping control and not letting the window events thread to run.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point starting a background thread if all you are going to do is to wait for it to finish.  Instead you can make the background thread do what you want to happen when it finishes.